# Parsing Chinese char using Java throwing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, inputstream, chinese-locale

I have an SoapMesagge in XML format which contain Chinese char.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<new:NewOperation xmlns:new="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/">
    <in>4)  软件应安全、。</in>
</new:NewOperation>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To parse this I wrote the code below in JAVA where soapMessage is my message

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapMessage.getBytes());
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8);
InputSource source=new InputSource(isr);
SAXParser parser = new SAXParser();
parser.parse(source);
```

It is not able to parse chinese char and throwing below error,please help me to solve this issue.

```
Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried with Dom Parser as well.

Comment: Check that the XML doesn't have a BOM : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark .

Comment: HI Thanks for update,I have tried using below code   `String s = soapMessage.replaceFirst("^\uFEFF", "");`    but my all chinese char getting changed into ???  this kind of string.      `<new:NewOperation xmlns:new="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/">
    <in>4) ?????</in>
</new:NewOperation>`

Comment: Where do you see the `????` , in the console ? Maybe it is unable to print those characters. Try outputting the values in a new file and check its content, or simply print the int value of each read character to ensure they aren't the `?` character .

Comment: It's possible that the encoding of your SOAP message is not UTF-8.
Save to file and open in binary editor to verify the presence of UTF-8 BOM (or BOMs from other UTF encodings). If you can, remove it manually. If you cannot modify the stream, see below answer for removing BOMs dynamically:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java/1835529#1835529

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below link, one answered is mentioned already, may help you.

[parsing chinese characters in java showing weird behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654146/parsing-chinese-characters-in-java-showing-weird-behaviour)

And I think your code should fail at compile time with below error also:

Code: `SAXParser parser = new SAXParser();`

Error: `Cannot instantiate the type SAXParser`

because **SAXParser**  is an abstract class you can't instantiate directly:

```
public abstract class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser
```